# Why would my AJAX request not work in Codepen.io?

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, codepen

I wasn’t able to make my AJAX request work for the first d3.js FreeCodeCamp project so far, so I decided to test whether if I copy some assignment that I already solved on FCC platform, replace a link with a full link to FCC (https://www.freecodecamp.org/json/cats.json) for the Cat Photo Finder and test whether the it will do anything once I press ‘get message’ button. However, nothing happens when I press on the corresponding button.

Here is my Codepen project for that: [Cat Photo Finder Pen](https://codepen.io/konstantinkrumin/pen/qBdJGgb)

What am I doing wrong here? Is there anything I would need to change in Codepen settings or import any statements to make it work?

Here my code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.getElementById('getMessage').onclick = function(){
      const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.open("GET",'https://www.freecodecamp.org/json/cats.json',true);
      req.send();
      req.onload = function(){
        const json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        let html = "";
        // Add your code below this line
        json.forEach(function(val) {
          const keys = Object.keys(val);
          html += "<div class = 'cat'>";
          keys.forEach(function(key) {
            html += "<strong>" + key + "</strong>: " + val[key] + "<br>";
          });
          html += "</div><br>";
        });
        // Add your code above this line
        document.getElementsByClassName('message')[0].innerHTML = html;
      };
    };
  });
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .box {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 20px 5px;
  }
  button {
    color: white;
    background-color: #4791d0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #4791d0;
    padding: 5px 10px 8px 10px;
  }
  button:hover {
    background-color: #0F5897;
    border: 1px solid #0F5897;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Cat Photo Finder</h1>
<p class="message box">
  The message will go here
</p>
<p>
  <button id="getMessage">
    Get Message
  </button>
</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in console? I think it has been blocked by [CORS policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: No, console doesn't give any errors

Comment: Is there anything I would need to do in the settings of my codepen page to override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to your XMLHttpRequest **has been blocked by CORS policy** becasue there is not any **`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`** header. Returned resource (your json) should have one. It might be atleast **`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`** which allows all domains.

This is not problem of codepen.io website. It's problem of the server where you host your json file. You can try another source. As [example](https://codepen.io/Jaxp/pen/ZEGqdRQ) I've used [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org) and tested your code with different source.

You can read more information about CORS at [MDN Web Docs - Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin).